# Other words for the cadaverous blue?

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for the particular word (if it exists in English) for the ghastly blue colour of a dead person...

Comment: Cadavers and dead people are not generally blue. What colour exactly are you talking about?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find an image to show you. I am talking about the colour of the face/lips, a mixture of blue, white and paleness. "The lurid blue"

Comment: In my country we use the term "bruisy", because the colour has that bluish nuance similar to bruises.

Comment: Pallor is not blue, it is pale or white. We wouldn't say the pallor of his lifeless lips, if we're talking about the cyanosis of the corpse's lips.

Comment: Depending on who you ask "ashen" is a pretty good word for this. Some people insist that is grey, but I wouldn't describe a dead person as blue unless cause of death was suffocation. I would say the ashen look of a very ill person is pretty close to someone already dead.

Comment: Are you talking about the *colour* or the *condition*?

Answer (score 16):

Pathological blue coloration of the skin is known as [*cyanosis*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cyanosis):

> a bluish or purplish discoloration (as of skin) due to deficient oxygenation of the blood

A particularly notorious manifestation of this symptom occurred during the pan-global influenza epidemic of 1918-1919, and was termed *heliotrope cyanosis* because of the resemblance to the colour of the heliotrope flower, particularly in the faces of sufferers from the disease (a result of the deterioration of their lungs).

Comment: This answer has the advantage of being correct.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - The fact that it is correct would not necessarily seen be seen as an advantage by many of this site's trigger-happy close-voters...

Comment: I only added the comment so that you would be targeted.

Comment: Trigger-happy? Syonara, blue man.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - That's pretty cute.

Comment: Did you realise that 'The Lone Ranger always uses perfect grammar and precise speech completely devoid of slang and colloquial phrases, at all times.' ( [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lone_Ranger) )!? McCawley's just been demoted into second place.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - "Hi-Yo" is apparently more formal than I had realised.

Comment: That's horsetalk, not English. (Are we off-topic yet?)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I do hope so.

Comment: Close-voted? We'll be lynched.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - If we're lucky, we might be buried in blue velvet. Or at least cyanotic velvet.

Comment: @ErikKowal - as suggested by OP in the notes, term should describe 'a mixture of blue, white and paleness'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, I disagree. This answer is incorrect. It refers to the coloration of a living person.  The question specifically states, in both the question and the body, about the bluish coloration observed in a dead person or that of a dead person (cadaverous).

Comment: @Ellie Kesselman. I assume you are a medic. I've seen the precising/stipulative definition barring the term from being used for corpses, but is it not possible for someone to die when actually exhibiting cyanosis? OP didn't clarify beyond ' I am talking about the colour of the face/lips'. But this surely rules out lividity?

Comment: Note also this example from [The Corpse: A History
By Christine Quigley](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pSjTAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=%22the+corpse%22+cyanosis%22&source=bl&ots=rnRik8fzrc&sig=ACfU3U0cKmstkTzgII8yza5PCU8_0VhIYA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJupzbhITpAhXsaRUIHY5EBVAQ6AEwCXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20corpse%22%20cyanosis%22&f=false): A cyanotic victim with protruding tongue, ... and petechiae on the face and whites of the eyes has almost certainly been strangled.' _So almost certainly dead._ In insisting on stipulative definitions, one must be specify range of authority.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Dying while suffering from cyanosis is an edge case, whereas dying from anything is the general case. The term for cadaverous blue of death is lividity, which is the general case. I'm not sure why you are so insistent on the correctness of a particular condition (cyanosis) being the answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In response to your second comment and source: You provided an example wherein cyanosis would be a correct description of a dead person's face, given specific circumstances associated with oxygen deprivation. The question does not mention oxygen deprivation, nor does it reference facial coloration. Cadaver refers to the entire body. This answer and your source refer to facial color only.

Comment: @Ellie Kesselman OP's comment after Janus's request for clarification: ' I am talking about the colour of the face/lips ...'.

Answer (score 13):

Livid or lividity is the correct term.

I can assure you that the recently dead are indeed blue. Rather, it depends upon the  position, *in situ* at time of death and in the hours shortly after. Blood pools when there is no heartbeat. Where it pools, there is dark blue discoloration, visible very clearly.

See "postmortem lividity" or "cadaveric lividity" [**[1](http://wordinfo.info/unit/1201/s:livid-)**]

> A purple coloration of dependent body parts, except in areas of
>   contact pressure, appearing within one half to two hours after death,
>   as a result of gravitational movement of blood within the vessels. The
>   coloration begins to form immediately after death and is usually
>   perceptible within two hours following the cessation of the
>   circulation of the blood in the body.

Also, see "lividity" [**[2](http://sesquiotic.wordpress.com/2014/06/16/livid/)**]

> Say, do you watch crime shows such as CSI? Do you
>   recognize the word lividity? What do they use this word in judging?
>   The colour of corpses. Lividity names a discoloration caused by blood
>   coagulating under the skin. This is one of the things that happen at a
>   predictable time after death: Latin *livor mortis*.

It is different than the color of bruising. When there is bruising, the discoloration is mottled. It may be more deeply discolored, almost black-purple, but it isn't as sad or disturbing, as it indicates that there is still a heartbeat, and life.

Comment: *Livid*, like *cleave* and *overlook*, contains its own antonym: as it means "furiously angry", it is associated (arguably improperly) with the red, flushed skin of a very angry person. From its etymology, I guess the Romans would say both "blue with anger" and "blue with jealousy", but modern English speakers have picked other colors.

Comment: @Malvolio this question is specifically about the coloration of a dead person, so the other meanings for livid would not apply as they are all attributes of living people.

Answer (score 10):

[Pallor](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pallor) may suggest the idea:

> - a pale condition, esp when unnatural: fear gave his face a deathly pallor.
> - unusual or extreme paleness, as from fear, ill health, or death.

Source:Collins English Dictionary

[Pallor mortis](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pallor_mortis):

> (Latin: pallor "paleness", mortis "of death") is a post mortem paleness which happens in those with light/white skin almost instantly (in the 15–25 minutes after the death) because of a lack of capillary circulation throughout the body.[1](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pallor) The blood sinks down into the lower parts (due to gravity) of the body creating livor mortis.

Source: http://en.m.wikipedia.org

Comment: *Pallor* of tissue describes the general decrease of its colour saturation, not an increase in its degree of blueness.

Comment: +1. You can use "pallid" if an adjective is needed.

Comment: ... or 'cyanotic' if you want people to have a chance to grasp that 'blue' is involved.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - as suggested in the notes by OP, the term should describe 'a mixture of blue, white and paleness'.

Comment: @Josh61 I've looked on the internet for images of bodies displaying cyanosis. Some are blueish and pallid, but more seem blueish / purplish on a red/reddish ground. I think the first comment by Janus exposes the weakness of the question. The question should be edited by OP, not clarification given in a later comment. // And I doubt that there is a single English word denoting both blueness and pallor.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - I agree,  a close-vote fon being 'unclear' is likely.

Comment: You also sometimes see Jaundice for about the first 10 minutes after death, depending on which organs fail first.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are good, but I think you have a better likelihood of being understood if you use the word **[ashen](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ashen)** instead:

> ashen (ˈæʃən)
>   adj
>   1. drained of colour; pallid
>   2. consisting of or resembling ashes
>   3. (Colours) of a pale greyish colour

Example sentences: **The ashen body laid lifeless on the floor.** Or **His face turned ashen as his vitality waned.** Or **The Borg appear ashen and even deathly.**<sup>1</sup>

In my experience, dead bodies do not typically look bluish, but that is more a matter of opinion than fact. Certainly, suffocated persons look bluish, but otherwise, I find they do not. They look pale or grayish even.

I would readily describe the look of a very ill person as ashen, and that same look carries into death as well.

---

1. [image: The Ashen face of Locutus]

Answer (score 2):

*Livid* was once the common adjective (Google or Google-book *livid corpse*), and *lividity* the noun. My impression is that  *livid* is now used colloquially only in the recent transferred sense of *angry* (from *livid with rage*), but it should be acceptable in a formal register.

Comment: It is still used medically and especially forensically.

Answer (score 0):

Lunar white.........................

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Answers on this network are expected to provide some explanation, including links to suitable references. Can you provide any examples in literature, for instance, where *lunar white* is used to refer to the pallor of a corpse? If not, why do you propose it?